# Use of atoi C++

Tags: c++, atoi

I've got the following function in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>    
bool isPrime(char myArr[])
{
    int myInt=atoi(myArr);
    int maxX=sqrt(myInt)+1;
    for(int x=0; x<maxX; x++)
    {
        if(!myInt%x)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I run it, Windows returns with a message box saying "Prime.c has stopped working" I have a feeling it's got something to do with the use of `atoi` though I'm not sure. Should `atoi` be used? Am I using it wrong? Or is it an entirely different problem?

Thanks

Comment: `atoi(3)` should probably not be used.  [`strtol(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/) accomplishes the same thing (and more), and can also let you know if it encountered an error.  I'm sure there's a more C++ way to do all of this stuff, though.

Comment: Windows just replies with a window saying: Prime.c has stopped working @BoBTFish

Comment: You are dividing by zero on the first step of the for cycle.

Comment: Also, your function is mixing concerns. It should take an int as input. Do the parsing of your user input (I assume that's what you pass as myArr) outside.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said: the loop is typically something like: `for ( int x = 3; x < maxX; x += 2 )` (with special casing for 2).

Comment: @Lewis "What's the error" means "have you even tried debugging the code?" Give us the line number of the error! For all we know, the mistake is in the code you haven't shown us if it's passing a bogus argument to `isPrime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have a problem with `atoi` specifically, though you aren't checking to see if it worked correctly.

The real problem is that your program divides by zero on the first iteration of the loop.  Start `x` at `2`:

```
for (int x = 2; x < maxX; x++)
```

You do have to start at `2`, too.   Starting at `1` will tell you that all of your numbers are prime, which isn't true and probably isn't what you want.  You might need a special case to handle `0` and `1` inputs - they're not prime, but will fall out of your current algorithm.

Editorial aside:  There are plenty of faster ways to check if a number is prime, if that's of use to you.

Comment: And if you special case 2, you can do `x += 2`, and make it run twice as fast.

Comment: Sure, and you can do it without a division in the loop or without the floating point `sqrt` operation, too.  If you want to speed it up, there's lots of ways.

Comment: Yes, but special casing 2 is a low hanging fruit.  `if ( x % 2 == 0 ) return x == 2; else ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I was agreeing with you. =)

Comment: can't do +=2, what about odds?

Comment: @cf16, he means start at `3` and use `+= 2`.  `2` is the only even prime number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to divide by 0, start at 2:

```
for (int x = 2; x < maxX; x++)
```

Comment: aha, ok, no problem, changed